# Updating cells in smartsheet (java)

Tags: java, cells, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

```
>Cell newCell = new Cell();
>newCell.setValue("no way");
>newCell.setColumnId(4303755236665220l);
>       
> connection = (HttpURLConnection) new >URL("https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/row/{row_id}/cells").openConnection();
>connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
>connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
>connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
>connection.setDoOutput(true);
>           
>            
>mapper.writeValue(connection.getOutputStream(), newCell);
>mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<Result<Cell>>() {});
>               
>System.out.println("cell added.");
```

This is my Java code to add a cell to the specified row.

It returns an error :-

"Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Request body must be either a JSON object or JSON array.
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/row/row_id/cells"

row_id has a Long value.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Update Row Cells](https://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.iivq0zgz3g8q) endpoint to add values to your cells. When using this endpoint the Smartsheet API is expecting the request body as an array of cells, rather than just a single cell object.

In your case, your request body looks like:

```
{"columnId": 4303755236665220l, "value": "no way"}
```

When you want to wrap that object in an array like this:

```
[{"columnId": 4303755236665220l, "value": "no way"} ]
```

You could also use the [Smartsheet Java SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-java-sdk). Using the SDK you would only need to make the following calls

```
 List<Cell> cells = new Cell.UpdateRowCellsBuilder().addCell(4303755236665220l, "no way").build();
 smartsheet.rows().updateCells({row_Id}, cells);
```

As a side note, this endpoint has been recently deprecated, and we enourage you to use the [Modify Row](https://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.4n7g0nv346f6) endpoint: `PUT /sheet/{sheetId}/row/{rowId}`

For this endpoint your request body would only modify slightly, as your array of cells would be wrapped in a row object, like so:

```
{"cells":[{"columnId": 4303755236665220l, "value": "no way"}]}
```